# How to use multiple DagBags in Airflow with WebUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, etl, google-cloud-composer

We are running Airflow 1.10.3 via Google Cloud Composer.

Our dags are distributed over several folders that we collect via instances of DagBag (like here  https://medium.com/@xnuinside/how-to-load-use-several-dag-folders-airflow-dagbags-b93e4ef4663c)

However the WebUI apparently can't find any DAGs that are not in the main dag folder (the one configured in airflow.cfg)
This seems to be because in `airflow.www.views` there is only one global variable `dagbag`.
Is that really the problem? What could be a workaround?

Additional info:

- `airflow list_dags` shows all dags
- the dags are also listed in the WebUI, and seem to get scheduled, but clicking the dag in the WebUI does only yields the error " does not seem to be in dagbag"

I'm curious to hear about your thoughts, since I'm pretty lost here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Cloud Composer [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations) the **dags_folder** parameter is blocked and can't be overridden (You're only allowed to use the the GCS bucket created by the Cloud Composer Environment). This allows Cloud Composer to upload DAGs, and that the dags folder remains in the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Due to the DAGBag can't be modified, and because Apache Airflow does not provide strong DAG isolation, it's recommend that you maintain separate your DAGs in different environments to prevent [DAG interference](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#before_you_begin).

I've made some test in my Composer environment creating multiple folders to separate my DAGs:

[image]

In all cases my Dags were recognized and ran as expected, even for sub-folders:

[image]

```
$ gcloud beta composer environments storage dags list  --environment=$ENVIRONMENT --location=us-east1
NAME
dags/
dags/airflow_monitoring.py
dags/dev/
dags/dev/airflow_monitoring_dev.py
dags/qa/
dags/qa/airflow_monitoring_qa.py
dags/qa/qa_test1/
dags/qa/qa_test1/airflow_monitoring_qa_test1.py
```

If recreate your folders in the dag folder created by Composer is not feasible for you. I recommend you synchronize content of your own bucket with the Composer dags folder, with the [rsync command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) you could mirror both buckets.